# What are the correct limits of integration here?

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

Say we have a differential equation in the following form and we want to integrate both sides to solve for P.

$$\frac{1}{P}dp = f(x)dx$$

The domain of $x$ is $(-\infty, \infty)$. The domain of $P$ is $(0, \infty)$

Which of the following is the correct answer and why?

$\ln P = \int_{-\infty}^{x}f(y)dy + c_1$

$\ln P = \int_{0}^{x}f(y)dy + c_1$

In my notes, it is was down as $-\infty$ to $x$ but then I crossed that out and changed it to $0$ to $x$. I don't remember the reason why the lecturer said it should be from $0$ to $x$?

Comment: Should not matter because $\int_{-\infty}^{0}f(y)dy\;$ is constant (if it exists) and you have to compute your $c_1$ according inital/boundary conditions anyway.

Comment: Why do we even have $x$ as the top limit of integration when we integrate both sides. I don't really get what is happening when we integrate both sides and the left hand side is treated as an indefinite integral yet the right hand side is now a definite integral plus a constant. Can someone explain the intuition behind what is happening when we integrate both sides?

Comment: The upper boundary is $x$ because you have the (implied) dependency $P=P(x),\;$ if not implied this should be stated more precisely.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the general solution, then it is usual to write an indefinite integral on both sides. If you want the particular solution such that $p(x_0)=p_0$ with $x_0\in(-\infty,\infty)$, $p_0\in(0,\infty)$ you write
$$
\int_{p_0}^p\frac{dz}{z}=\int_{x_0}^xf(x)\,dx.
$$
If $\int_{-\infty}^xf(y)\,dy$ exists and you want the solution such that $\lim_{x\to-\infty}p(x)=p_0$ then you write
$$
\int_{p_0}^p\frac{dz}{z}=\int_{-\infty}^xf(x)\,dx.
$$